# How to compare 2 custom lists of lego details?

Tags: technic, bricklink

I have a `.lxf` file for MOC. With Bricklink Studio I can create a list of details for it.

In Rebrickable I have a list of all parts that I own. Do we have a way to get somehow a list a details for this MOC that I do not own?

Rebrickable has this feature for sets and MOCs, but I can't find an option for custom lists.

Answer (score 4):

First you need to create a Custom list on Rebrickable with contents of LXF file you got from Stud.io. Then you go to [Compare sets](https://rebrickable.com/sets/compare/slow/) where you have an option to compare a MOC vs your Custom List. You can find needed MOC by either its MOC ID or by its name in "Set Num" field. Custom List can be selected from drop-down menu.